# Finding rotation and translation using (residual) vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, transformation

[image]

As illustrated in Fig.1 I have $n$ (blue) straight lines represented by $F = \{f_1(x),f_2(x) \dots f_n(x)\}$. These lines passes through the (yellow) straight line $g(x)$. Similarly $X = \{\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \dots \mathbf{x}_n \}$ are sample points that lie on $g(x)$ and lie close to the intersecting points between $f_1(x),f_2(x)  \dots f_n(x)$ and $g(x)$. The red (residual) vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2  \dots \mathbf{v}_n$ are obtained by connecting the sample points with its corresponding intersecting points.
$$\textbf{v}_n = \bar{X}_n - X_n$$
$\qquad$ where $\bar{X}$ is the set of intersecting points between $F$ and $g(x)$.
All the values of the points, lines and vectors are assumed to be known.

My goal is to find $\hat{g}(x)$ (as shown in Fig.2) or in other words to rotate and translate $g(x)$ and the sample points in such a way that the size of the (residual) vectors becomes smaller after the transformation. Note that the distances between sample points remain unchanged after the transformation; that is

$$||\mathbf{x}_{n} - \mathbf{x}_{n - 1}|| = || \mathbf{x}_{n}' - \mathbf{x}_{n - 1}'|| \qquad \mathrm{where} \,\,  n = 1,2, \cdots N$$

If $X' = \{\mathbf{x}_1', \mathbf{x}_2', \cdots \mathbf{x}_n'\}$  that lies on $\hat{g}(x)$ as shown in Fig.2 is the set containing the transformed (Rotation and Translation) sample points than there exists a Rotation $\mathbf{R}$ and Translation $\mathbf{T}$ such that
$$X' =  \mathbf{R} X  + \mathbf{T}$$

Finding the best transformation here is to minimize the sum of the square of the  *residual* vectors. Thus

$$ \sum_i || \bar{X}_i' - (\mathbf{R} X_i  + \mathbf{T})||^2 \rightarrow \mathrm{min}$$

$\qquad$ where $\bar{X}'_i$ is the set of intersecting points between $F$ and $\hat{g}(x)$ and itself depends on $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{T}$. How would one proceed further from here?
**The constraints:**  the sample points  of $X$ and $X'$ are collinear and that the spacing between the sample points remain unchanged.

Is it possible to solve this problem by exploiting the information (magnitude and direction) contained in the vectors? Or in other words, is the information contained in the vectors sufficient to tell me which direction $g(x)$ must be moved so that it ends up at $\hat{g}(x)$?

Comment: This problem just has two unknown parameters. Can we see your formulation of the iterative method ? And why do you reject an iterative method ?

Comment: "the distances between sample points must be preserved" is of course impossible to achieve exactly. What scalar criterion do you want to use ?

Comment: Why is it impossible to achieve exactly? Any ridid transformation preserves the euclidian distance between the sample points, no? What exactly do you mean by scalar criterion?

Comment: Because there are more equations than unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assume that you fix the rotation angle $\theta$ of $g(x)$ around some fixed point. Let the coordinates of the intersection points with the lines $f_k$ be $(u_k,v_k)$ and let the slopes of these lines be $s_k$. Let the distances between the points $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ be $d_{k,k+1}$.

We can find an "optimal" translation of horizontal component $t$ by solving the least-squares problem

$$\min_t\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}((u_{k+1}-u_k)^2+(v_{k+1}-v_k+t(s_{k+1}-s_k))^2-d_{k,k+1}^2)^2.$$

This leads to a cubic equation, which can be solved analytically. From the value of $t$, we can draw the residual error $E(\theta)$. Then the problem is reduced to 1D minimization.

---

Expressing $u,v$ in terms of $\theta$, you will get linear functions of the form $a+b\cos\theta+c\sin\theta$ and the above cost function is a bivariate mixed trigonometric polynomial of degree four. This amounts to a polynomial equation of a higher degree (like eight, but I am unsure). Chances for an analytical solution are zero or less.

---

Other criteria than the above least-squares can be used. This will only make the resolution harder.

Comment: Cannot I exploit the information contained in the vectors to find the approximate direction of rotation and translation?

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc: if you don't want an iterative solution, an approximate direction is of strictly no use.

Comment: As illustrated in Fig.2, $\hat{g}(x)$ is not only translated about positive $x-$axis but also rotated slightly in the ccw direction in comaprision to $g(x)$. How would one compute the optimal rotation?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and Hint really..
I am somewhat new in this field. What books and authors would you recommend in order to tackle this problem?

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc: lookup "least-squares minimization".

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you came up with the expression for *optimal* translation of horizontal component $t$?

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc: means with minimum error. Read about least-squares fitting.

Comment: The idea behind least-squares fitting is in my opinion preety straight forward. Do you mean that the vectors (red arrows) do not contain ANY information about the direction in which $g(x)$ must be moved? My guess was one could use the information in the vectors as a force *pushing* $g(x)$ towards the optimal $\hat{g}(x)$ such that sum of the squares of the error is minimized.

How can one show analytically that the vectors are redundant?

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc: I said that if you don't want an ITERATIVE solution, an APPROXIMATE direction is of strictly no use. Your question WAS SAYING "... but that is exactly what I want to avoid".

Comment: "an APPROXIMATE direction is of strictly no use". I have posted an answer with a figure which might simplify the discussion.

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc: not at all. You don't seem to appreciate or care about the difference between a direct and an iterative method, nor worry about silently changing the question.